# How to use pyodbc to migrate tables from MS Access to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I need to migrate tables from MS Access to Postgres. I'd like to use pyodbc to do this as it allows me to connect to the Access database using python and query the data.

The problem I have is I'm not exactly sure how to programmatically create a table with the same schema other than just creating a SQL statement using string formatting. pyodbc provides the ability to list all of the fields, field types and field lengths, so I can create a long SQL statement with all of the relevant information, however how can I do this for a bunch of tables? would I need to build SQL string statements for each table?

```
import pyodbc

access_conn_str = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; 'r'DBQ=C:\Users\bob\access_database.accdb;')
access_conn = pyodbc.connect(access_conn_str)
access_cursor = access_conn.cursor()

postgres_conn_str = ("DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};""DATABASE=access_database;""UID=user;""PWD=password;""SERVER=localhost;""PORT=5433;")
postgres_conn = pyodbc.connect(postgres_conn_str)
postgres_cursor = postgres_conn.cursor()

table_ditc = {}
row_dict = {}

for row in access_cursor.columns(table='table1'):
    row_dict[row.column_name] = [row.type_name, row.column_size]

table_ditc['table1'] = row_dict

for table, values in table_ditc.items():
    print(f"Creating table for {table}")

    access_cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {table}')
    result = access_cursor.fetchall()

    postgres_cursor.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE {table} (Do I just put a bunch of string formatting in here?);''')
    postgres_cursor.executemany(f'INSERT INTO {table} (Do I just put a bunch of string formatting) VALUES (string formatting?)', result)

postgres_conn.commit()
```

As you can see, with pyodbc I'm not exactly sure how to build the SQL statements. I know I could build a long string by hand, but if I were doing a bunch of different tables, with different fields etc. that would not be realistic. Is there a better, easier way to create the table and insert rows based off of the schema of the Access database?

Comment: Have you looked around for existing tools that might take care of the grunt work for you? Something like [this](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Data-migration), perhaps?

Comment: @GordThompson No I haven't looked into other tools. What you suggested looks pretty neat, I'll check it out.

Comment: [MDB-tools](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools). Example: `mdb-schema -T some_table some_db.mdb postgres`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I gave MDB-tools a shot. When I export the tables with this command ```mdb-schema access_database.accdb postgres | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | psql -d postgres_database -U postgres -W -h 192.168.0.242 -p 5433``` It creates all of the tables but then at the end I get two errors - ERROR: relation "msysnavpanegroups" does not exist ERROR: relation "msysnavpanegrouptoobjects" does not exist I also get errors when trying to load the data (its looping and saying column does not exist). Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Well first of all I would direct the output of `mdb-schema` to a file first, in order to verify the output.  Any time you migrate from one system to another there will be mismatches.  Is there `msysnavpanegroups` table in the Access database? Is it in the output produced by `mdb-schema`?  What column does not exist and what is the exact error? Add the answers to above to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I ran ```mdb-schema access_database.accdb > schema.txt``` and did NOT see those two tables. I also don't see them when I view the database in Access. Are they hidden tables or something? 

When I try to load data, the error is 
```ERROR:  column "21" does not exist``` But it's repeated for what appears to be every record in the table. but the column name changes e.g. 198, 589, 325 etc. 

It looks like these numbers are records in a particular column, not columns, so I'm not sure why for each record it's saying column does not exist.

Comment: Figured out the insert issue. I had to add the -q flag like this ```mdb-export -I postgres -q "'" access_database.accdb table1 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | psql -d postgres_database -U postgres -W -h 192.168.0.242 -p 5433```

Comment: @fpolig01 - If you have found a solution please consider posting an Answer that briefly explains what you did. That will make it easier for the next person to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ultimately ended up using a combination of `pyodbc` and `pywin32`. `pywin32` is "basically a very thin wrapper of python that allows us to interact with COM objects and automate Windows applications with python" (quoted from second link below).

I was able to programmatically interact with Access and export the tables directly to Postgres with `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase
https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html

```
import win32com.client
import pyodbc
import logging
from pathlib import Path

conn_str = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; 'rf'DBQ={access_database_location};')
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

a = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
a.OpenCurrentDatabase(access_database_location)

table_list = []

for table_info in cursor.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    table_list.append(table_info.table_name)

for table in table_list:
    logging.info(f"Exporting: {table}")

    acExport = 1
    acTable = 0
    db_name = Path(access_database_location).stem.lower()

    a.DoCmd.TransferDatabase(acExport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"f"DATABASE={db_name};"f"UID={pg_user};"f"PWD={pg_pwd};""SERVER=localhost;"f"PORT={pg_port};", acTable, f"{table}", f"{table.lower()}_export_from_access")

    logging.info(f"Finished Export of Table: {table}")
    logging.info("Creating empty table in EGDB based off of this")
```

This approach seems to be working for me. I like how the creation of the table/fields as well as insertion of data is all handled automatically (which was the original problem I was having with `pyodbc`).

If anyone has better approaches I'm open to suggestions.