# Migrating .mdb database to .accdb (Pyodbc)

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I try to convert an old MS Access database with the file-extension ".mdb" to the newer ".accdb"-format. I got the idea of using Pyodbc because the newer versions of MS Access refuse to open the old file. So far I succeeded in connecting to the .mdb and reading the table-names from the old file with Pyodbc.
Is there a way to connect to the .mdb, grab its contents and save it to a .accdb or maybe copying the data table by table into an empty .accdb?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version created the mdb and what version are you running? Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614826/how-to-use-pyodbc-to-migrate-tables-from-ms-access-to-postgres?msclkid=73e01db6cf8011ecbeddecd7b9bedefa. Use the `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` command. Or export tables to Excel or CSV then import to new db. Or find someone running Access 2010-2016.

Comment: It depends. Are you use JET or ACE for the data engine? JET (older) can read and use mdb files. ACE can read mdb files - just not really older formats. And you MUST use ACE in place of JET to read + use accDB files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new accdb database and import all objects from the old mdb format. This should usually work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).